# What is generalized policy iteration?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, definitions, value-iteration, policy-iteration

I am reading Sutton and Barto's material now. I know value iteration, which is an iterative algorithm taking the maximum value of adjacent states, and policy iteration. But what is generalized policy iteration?

Answer (score 3):

In the standard policy iteration algorithm presented in Sutton and Barto's book, you alternate between a policy evaluation (PE) step and a policy improvement (PI) step (i.e. PE, PI, PE, PI, PE, PI, PE, ...). However, in general, you don't have to follow this alternation *strictly* in order to converge (in the limit) to the optimal policy. For example, value iteration (VI) is an example of a *truncated* policy iteration that still converges to the optimal policy.

The term [*generalized policy iteration* (GPI)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node46.html) refers to all algorithms based on policy iteration, such as value iteration, that alternate *in some order* PI and PE, and that are guaranteed to converge to the optimal policy, provided PE and PI are executed enough times.